# Grouping data into bins and calculating % above threshold

Tags: python, graph

I actually have working code for this problem but it's cumbersome and probably a stupid way to do it (python beginner here), so I'm hoping someone can provide a better solution.

I have a database with a few thousand text passages. For each one I have calculated the average word length and a score. I would like to divide the word length into bins (0.25 steps in this example) and get the percentage of text snippets in each bin that are above a certain threshold and then graph the whole thing.

Here's the code that I have right now. It's obviously stupidly long for this task and if I want to change the size of my bins I'd have to rewrite a lot of lines. What would be a better way to do it?

```
WL40 = []
WL42 = []
WL45 = []
WL47 = []
WL50 = []
WL52 = []
WL55 = []
WL57 = []
WL60 = []
WL62 = []
WL65 = []
WL67 = []
WL70 = []
WL72 = []     

ScoreTarget = 100 #This is the threshold

for line in text_table:
    if line.TextWordCount>20 and line.AverageWordLength>3.5 and line.AverageWordLength<7.25:
        if line.AverageWordLength<=4:
            WL40.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL40.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>4 and line.AverageWordLength<=4.25:
            WL42.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL42.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>4.25 and line.AverageWordLength<=4.5:
            WL45.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL45.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>4.5 and line.AverageWordLength<=4.75:
            WL47.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL47.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>4.75 and line.AverageWordLength<=5:
            WL50.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL50.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>5 and line.AverageWordLength<=5.25:
            WL52.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL52.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>5.25 and line.AverageWordLength<=5.5:
            WL55.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL55.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>5.5 and line.AverageWordLength<=5.75:
            WL57.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL57.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>5.75 and line.AverageWordLength<=6:
            WL60.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL60.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>6 and line.AverageWordLength<=6.25:
            WL62.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL62.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>6.25 and line.AverageWordLength<=6.5:
            WL65.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL65.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>6.5 and line.AverageWordLength<=6.75:
            WL67.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL67.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>6.75 and line.AverageWordLength<=7:
            WL70.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL70.append(1)
        if line.AverageWordLength>7 and line.AverageWordLength<=7.25:
            WL72.append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else WL72.append(1)

Ychance = []
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL40))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL42))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL45))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL47))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL50))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL52))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL55))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL57))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL60))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL62))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL65))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL67))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL70))
Ychance.append(np.mean(WL72))

Xchance = [4,
           4.25,
           4.5,
           4.75,
           5,
           5.25,
           5.5,
           5.75,
           6,
           6.25,
           6.5,
           6.75,
            7,
            7.25]

plt.scatter(Xchance, Ychance)
plt.show
```

Comment: Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

Comment: I had taken a look at that but I really don't know how I would use it here. pandas.cut only takes 1D arrays but in my case the bin depends on X (WordLength) and the binned value depends on Y (Score)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range_list = [4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25]
Xchance = range_list
Ychance = []

dct_map = {}
ScoreTarget = 100

for line in text_table:
    if line.TextWordCount>20 and line.AverageWordLength>3.5 and line.AverageWordLength<7.25:
        for range_val in range_list:
            if line.AverageWordLength <= range_val:
                key = "WL"+str(int(range_val*10))
                if key not in dct_map:
                    dct_map[key] = []
                dct_map[key].append(0) if line.Score<ScoreTarget else dct_map[key].append(1)
                break


for k in sorted(dct_map):
    Ychance.append(np.mean(dct_map[k]))

plt.scatter(Xchance, Ychance)
plt.show
```

Use this code. Try and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: First of all, thank you. This code definitely already taught me quite a bit. It seems to work but gives me quite different results to my existing version. I'm trying to find the reason at the moment.

My version gives [0.0034013605442176869, 0.0041493775933609959, 0.0053160070880094506, 0.0065882352941176473,...]

Yours gives [0.0065882352941176473, 0.010816125860373648, 0.0041493775933609959, 0.0097087378640776691,...]

Comment: Just print Xchance and Ychance of my code . Is it same as per your output?

Comment: The Xchance yes, the Ychance no - the lists in my previous comment were the first few items of the Ychance of our respective codes. I can upload an image of the respective graphs if that's any help.

Comment: replace for loop with this code ---->>
for k in sorted(dct_map):
    Ychance.append(np.mean(dct_map[k]))

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! Could you tell me what the issue was? Just for my own benefit. Thanks!

Comment: Element in the list of Ychance was shuffled and it was  not proper as per your output.

Comment: Oh, I should have seen that. Thanks.